# R data.table: referring to data table column with externally assigned column name

Tags: r, data.table

I am reading in a large amount of files with monthly price information per product.

I want to obtain a data table merging all these files.

The key of this table is going to be the 2 columns with a product identifier and the date.

A third column then contains the retail price.

In the source files each price column has a name of the format RETAILPRICE_[dd.mm.yyyy].

To prevent my final data table from containing a large amount of columns I need to rename the column with the retail price and to create a new column containing the date.

The following code runs into an error because `data.table` does not understand the external reference to one of its columns.

```r
# this is how I obtain the list of files that have to be read in
# list the files
# files <- list.files(path = "path",
#                    pattern = "^Publications.*$",
#                    full.names = T)

# the data looks like this, although it is contained in an excel file.
# sample data
ProdID <- list(836187, 2398159, 2398165, 2398171, 2398188, 1800180, 2320105, 2320128, 2320140, 2320163, 1714888, 2516340)
RETAILPRICE_01.01.2003 <- c(12.50, 43.50, 65.50, 45.60, 69.45, 21.30, 81.15, 210.70, 405.00, 793.60, 116.50, 162.60)
Publications_per_2003.01.01 <- data.table(ProdID,RETAILPRICE_01.01.2003)

# uncomment if you want to write this to excel
# using .xls on purpose, because that's what they used back in the days
# xlsx::write.xlsx(Publications_per_2003.01.01,
#    "Publications_per_2003.01.01.xls",
#    row.names = F)
# files <- list.files(path = "path",
#                    pattern = "^Publications.*$",
#                    full.names = T)

# create data table
price_list <- data.table(
                 prodID = character(),
                 date = character(),
                 retail_price = numeric())


price_list <- lapply(files, function(x){

  # obtain date from file name
  # date in file name has the structure yyyy_mm_dd
  # while in the column name date has the structure
  # dd.mm.yyyy
  date <- substr(sapply(strsplit(x,"_"),"[",3),1,10)

  # obtain day, month and year separately
  day <- substr(date,9,10)
  month <- substr(date,6,7)
  year <- substr(date,1,4)

  # store the name of the column containing the retail price
  priceVar <- as.name(paste0("RETAILPRICE_",day,".",month,".",year))

  # read the xls file with the price info and in one go
  # keep only the relevant columns
  file <- data.table(read_excel(x))[
    ,.(prodID= as.character(ProdID),
       retail_price = priceVar,
       date = as.character(gsub("\\.","-",date)))#,with = F
    ]

  # merge the new file with the existing data table
  price_list <- merge(price_list,file,"ProdID")
})
```

This results in the error message

```
Error in rep(x[[i]], length.out = mn) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'symbol'
```

If I comment the part

```
retail_price = priceVar,
```

there's no error.

So the problem lies in the reference to the column that somehow is not working.

I also tried

```
priceVar <- as.name(paste0("RETAILPRICE_",day,".",month,".",year))

file <- data.table(read_excel(x))

setnames(file, priceVar, "retail_price")
```

but I get the error (column name modified to fit the example):

```
Error in setnames(file, priceVar, "retail_price") : 
  Items of 'old' not found in column names: RETAILPRICE_dd.mm.yyyy.
```

If anyone could enlighten me I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: Do you really need to use data.table here? Using good old data frames with a column selection would be simpler: `read_excel(x)[, c("ProdID", paste0("RETAILPRICE_",day,".",month,".",year))]`. Then, set column names as you want them.

Comment: Another point: you cannot modify the global variable `price_list` inside a function. With what you wrote, a local copy of `price_list` will be created inside the function and the merge result will be returned invisibly. But the global variable won't be modified and you won't have the cumulative effect you are expecting. Solution: function returns `file`, and extra step after `lapply(...)` : `file_list <- do.call(rbind, file_list)`

Comment: Since it is a large amount of files I'd prefer to use `data.table` since it's faster.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on the merge. Was not focussing on that part yet. Will implement it.

Comment: It won't make a difference in this case: `read_excel` returns a `tibble` so you will have to pay the price of the conversion to `data.table`. Since you only have 3 columns there is no direct need for this conversion, even if the number of rows is large

Comment: depending on what you want to do after, it may be useful to convert to data.table, but after the lapply loop and the rbind

Comment: You're absolutely right. Definitely solves my current problem. If you make you comment into an answer I'll accept it, although I'd still be curious to know why this works for a data frame, but not for a data table.

Comment: @PierreGramme there is no price of conversion if you use `setDT`

Comment: @jangorecki you're right it's almost nothing, thanks for pointing it out! But in the code presented here, I think there is also no win to use it

Comment: @o_v: data.table has to determine whether `priceVar` is an explicit column name in your Excel file or whether it must first be evaluated into a character which is the column name. That's tricky. In `dplyr` you would use `select(.data, !!sym(paste0("RETAILPRICE_",day,".",month,".",year)))`. I'm not an expert in data table, can't translate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it will be much easier to work with plain data frames rather than data.table's.

```r
price_list <- lapply(files, function(x){
  date <- substr(sapply(strsplit(x,"_"),"[",3),1,10)

  day <- substr(date,9,10)
  month <- substr(date,6,7)
  year <- substr(date,1,4)

  # make it a character, not a name
  priceVar <- paste0("RETAILPRICE_",day,".",month,".",year)

  one_df <- readxl::read_excel(x)[, c("ProdID", priceVar)]
  colnames(one_df) <- c("prodID", "retail_price")
  one_df$prodID = as.character(one_df$prodID) # NB: as.integer would be much more efficient, but be careful for values above 2.0e9
  one_df$date = as.character(gsub("\\.","-",date))

  one_df
})

# Watch out: this will pile up the records from all files
# In your initial code you were using merge(...) which computes the intersection
price_list <- do.call(rbind, price_list)

# Optional:
data.table::setDT(price_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be nice if you provide an sample of the data you're working with so we could try your code with the data sample.
Also I read your code and on this line :

```
price_list <- merge(prijslijst,file,"ProdID")
```

You never mentioned the variable "prijslijst" so maybe the problem is there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I translated the variable names to improve understanding, but I ensure you this is not the source of the problem. I will add a data sample.